# Setting and retrieving session works in Postman but not working in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, postman

I am working with this NodeJS project using `express-session` to create session for my application. The problem is, when I make a `post` request to the `http://localhost:5500/login`, a session is created with additional property `userid` that I added intentionally. Then, when I use Postman to make a `get` request to `http://localhost:5500/`, the application actually receives the session with the property `userid` and redirect the user to his home page based on the `userid` is set or not. However, if I make `get` request to `http://localhost:5500/` from a browser like Chrome, my server is not able to get the session with the additional property `userid' that I added when log in successfully and does not redirect my user to his home page. Can anyone explain why this happens  please? Thank you

Here is the code of my `index.js`
`

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5500
const session = require("express-session")
const { routers } = require("./routes/routes")
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser")

const TIME = 1000 * 60 * 5
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(
    session({
        secret: "iamnamdo1234567",
        saveUninitialized: true,
        cookie: { maxAge: TIME, sameSite: "strict" },
        resave: false
    })
)
const URI = process.env.DB_CONNECTION
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(express.json())
app.use("/api", routers)
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    let session = req.session.userid
    session ? res.status(200).send("Hello my friend, you are logged in") : res.status(400).send("You need to log in")
})

mongoose.connect(URI, { useNewUrlParser: true.valueOf(), useUnifiedTopology: true }, err => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        console.log("database connected")
    }
})
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Go to http://localhost:${PORT}`)
})
```

`

This is the code of my `routes.js`
`

```
const express = require("express")
const route = express.Router()
const { User } = require("../models/User")
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt")

const errorHandler = (type, error) => {
    if (type === "register") {
        if (error.code === 11000) {
            return { message: "Username has been taken" }
        } else if (error._message === "User validation failed") {
            return { message: error.errors.username?.properties.message || error.errors.password?.properties.message }
        }
    } else if (type === "login") {
        return { message: `${error}` }
    }
}

route.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { username, password } = req.body
        const user = await User.create({ username, password })
        res.status(200).send("User has been created successfully")
    } catch (error) {
        // console.log(error)
        let message = errorHandler("register", error)
        res.status(400).send(message)
    }
})
route.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ username })
        if (!user) {
            throw (new Error().message = "Username not found")
        }
        const checkPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
        if (checkPassword === false) {
            throw (new Error().message = "Password is incorrect")
        } else {
            req.session.userid = user.username
            console.log(req.session.userid)
            res.status(200).send("Logged in")
        }
    } catch (error) {
        let message = errorHandler("login", error)

        res.status(400).send(message)
    }
})
route.post("/logout", (req, res) => {
    req.session.destroy()
    res.redirect("/")
})
module.exports.routers = route
```

`

I tried to access the session when making `get` request from the browser

Comment: When running in ```localhost```, the ```secure``` param in cookie should be set to ```false```. You can do something like this, ```secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'```

Comment: I add `secure: false` to the session but it still doesn't work in the browser (Postman is working just fine).

Answer (score 1):

If the session details are visible in Postman but not in the browser, it could be due to a number of reasons, one of them is Cookie policy.
By default, cookies are only sent with requests made to the same origin as the current page. To send cookies with cross-origin requests, you need to set the withCredentials option in Axios. Try this it worked for me

const axios = require('axios');

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;